# How to solve this code duplication in an elegant way? [reactjs]

Tags: reactjs

How would you simplify this small react component.
I'm not happy with repeating the html elements but I got no clean way to do it.
The reason it's not so obvious for me is because there is a small logic in the latter case that needs to be dealth with.

```
const RemainingSessionTime = (props: RemainingSessionTimeProps) => {
  const { model, showTitle } = props;

  if (model.remainingTime == -1) {
    return (
      <div className="gadget longContent remainingTime">
        {showTitle && <div className="title">{title}</div>}
        <div className="value">
          <span>-</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
    
  const isCalculated = model.valueType === ValueTypes.CALCULATED;
    
  return (
    <div className="gadget longContent remainingTime">
      {props.showTitle && <div className="title">{title}</div>}
      <div className="value">
        {isCalculated && <span>~</span>}
        <span>{t}</span>
        <span>{model.remainingTime < 3600 ? "m" : "h"}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can encapsulate the logic into another component like:

```
return (
  <div className="gadget longContent remainingTime">
    {showTitle && <div className="title">{title}</div>}
    <div className="value">
      <ShowTime remainingTime={model.remainingTime} isCalculated={false} t='t' />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

The new ShowTime component:

```
function ShowTime({ remainingTime, isCalculated, t }) {
  return isCalculated && remainingTime === -1 ? (
    <span>~</span>
  ) : (
    <span>
      {t}
      {remainingTime < 3600 ? "m" : "h"}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution but the symbols kind of mess up the html code too much to my liking

Comment: I see. You might think of encapsulating that into another one or two functional components, like <ShowTime .. />

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that.. @Iamisti

Comment: yeah I think this is the cleanest solution. Unfortunately you need to create a new component for it but I guess that's okay.

Comment: accepted your answer but you need to edit the code a bit. Your component is not used in your example and you also have two return statement next to each other.

Comment: I thought you don't like the ternary operator! Hope it looks better now : )

Answer (score -1):

```
const RemainingSessionTime = (props: RemainingSessionTimeProps) => {
  const { model, showTitle } = props;

 if (model.remainingTime == -1) {
  return (
   <div className="gadget longContent remainingTime">
      {showTitle && <div className="title">{title}</div>}
    <div className="value">
      <span>-</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   );
 }

  const isCalculated = model.valueType === ValueTypes.CALCULATED;

 return (
<div className="gadget longContent remainingTime">
  {props.showTitle && <div className="title">{title}</div>}
  <div className="value">
    {isCalculated && <span>~</span>}
    <span>{t}</span>
    <span>{model.remainingTime < 3600 ? "m" : "h"}</span>
  </div>
 </div>
  );
}
```